# NetSuite saved search filter records with min quantity

Tags: netsuite

How do I apply following requirement in Saved Search criteria?

> Filter all inventory items
>
> Where min( {memberitem.quantityavailable} / {memberquantity} ) <> custitem_quantity

*Note: `custitem_quantity` is a custom numeric field.*

*Note2: NetSuite is throwing error when I use `min` function in filters.*

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Again your query is incomplete. Thats may be the reason why it underlooked by the group users. I see your query and I observed you're trying to use min() as an arithmetic function, which obviously not the way it works. The MIN() function can be used to return the smallest value of the selected column. If you want to get the minimum value of  `({memberitem.quantityavailable} / {memberquantity} )` then probably depending on your context you would like to go for `CIEL() /FLOOR() /ROUND()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one issue here.

You have to be careful with custom numerics in Netsuite.

When your inner condition evaluates, it does not have the same type because it is fractional.  At some point it has to be rounded and / or truncated internally. The other side of the expression would need to call a floor or ceiling function to remove everthing past the decimal.

Also, the min function evaluates after the <> conditional, which will be dependent upon whether your custom numeric is type compatible to begin with.

In the expression you provided us, it would have to be an exact match (and an exact type), and that is before you consider whether MIN gets to be evaluated.

Look at how the datatypes are cast and what columns you are processing because memberitem.quantityavailable may need a secondary index depending upon your dependencies and where the formula is being called.  If this formula is being used over multiple products, it may not be logically consistent.

When I have similar items in inventory that I want to generate stats for I try to process it separately, even if I have to make a second pass.

What are you trying to isolate exactly - - I cannot think of a quantity-related situation where there would be a need to use division in this way - - please refer to the formula Mike Robbins listed above for a properly structured evaluation and see if it achieves the desired result.

If you post the rest of your code, I will help you resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The entire expression is not valid and will not evaluate due to the conditional shown, the MIN, nor the division.  Index the count on the memberquantity if you are looking to sum over values.  Otherwise, CountIF will work for quantities.  MIN will only finds the lowest value in a given column, so SumIF appears to be what you are after.  You can create a second expression which bounds the values you are searching for as a preliminary step.

I am new here, so please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish so I can earn the bounty.

Comment: The expression in question is just the raw requirement from one of our customers. Could you please provide sample expression for what you are suggesting?

Comment: Zain, three of us have all asked for clarification from you.  We need to know in plain english statements what you are trying to filter.  You also need to let us know what type of custom numeric field, otherwise you are wasting all of our time here.  SE works best when we can get specifics from posters, otherwise we will move on to other questions where we can interact.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take into account null values as well to avoid errors or inconsistent data.

If you're using formula numeric, try this:

Formula(Numeric):

```
case when min((NVL({memberitem.quantityavailable},0) / NVL({memberquantity},0)) - (NVL{custitem_quantity},0)) then 1 else 0 end
```

'IS EQUAL TO' 1

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the Formula Text or Formula Numeric Search Filter for that.

Comment: could you please provide any sample? I tried but I do not find any way to compare two fields in filter as mentioned in question.

Comment: The way that I compare two numeric field values in a filter is to subtract one from the other and compare it against zero.  While I haven't tested your specific example because I'm not sure what the ultimate goal is, using your formula it would look something like `min({memberitem.quantityavailable} / {memberquantity}) - {custitem_quantity}` not equal to `0`

Comment: @MikeRobbins have you tested this code? I tried but NetSuite is throwing error when I use `min` function in filters.

Comment: Can you explain in words what are you planning to accomplish with the filter?  Why divide the quantity available against the member quantity and why the need to compare it to the custitem_quantity